# AWS: How to update an existing S3 bucket-policy via CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have an existing S3 bucket `my-bucket`.

I am writing a new CloudFormation template file which creates some new AWS resource that interacts with `my-bucket`. Now, my business use-case requires me to add a new permission statement to the bucketpolicy for `my-bucket` *from within the CloudFormation template file*.

```yaml
SourceBucketBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: my-bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              - 's3:PutBucketNotificationConfiguration'
            Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            Principal:
              AWS: !GetAtt MyLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
```

The problem is that the bucket already has the following bucket-policy that was added by someone else manually via the AWS Console at some point in the past. It's an important bucket-policy from a business perspective so I cannot get rid of it:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3-Policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DataCraft-012345678901-S3-datacraft",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::012345678901:user/datacraft"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I guess my only option is to *update* the existing bucket-policy to additionally accommodate my new policy statement. The question is: how can I do that through the CloudFormation template file?

**EDIT:** For those interested, I eventually solved the problem by writing an `AWS::IAM::Policy` instead of `AWS::S3::BucketPolicy`:

```yaml
SourceBucketNotificationConfigurationPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: s3:PutBucketNotification
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        Version: '2012-10-17'
      PolicyName: BucketNotificationsRolePolicy
      Roles:
        - Ref: MyLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, you **can't update** an existing policy which is not managed by CloudFormation.

The only thing you can do is to **replace policy** in the bucket using CloudFormation by recreating it.

What's more, existing bucket policies **can't be imported** into CloudFormation. The reason is that `AWS::S3::BucketPolicy` is not a supported resource for [importing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html).

**Edit: Based on [@JeremyThompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495455/jeremy-thompson)'s [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62906674#comment111243590_62906749)**

I verified the use of `UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain`.

For that I used my own bucket and with policy. Both were created outside of CloudFormation, using the AWS console.

Then, I created a CFN template with `AWS::S3::BucketPolicy`. The deployment of the template **failed**, with or without `UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain` with error message:

```
The bucket policy already exists on bucket <bucket-name>.
```

This means that you can't replace existing bucket policy. The policy must be recreated in CloudFormation.

Comment: Really? If you set the `UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain` can't you then safely replace the S3 Buckets Policy? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatereplacepolicy.html

Comment: @JeremyThompson My understanding is that the OP want's to add or modify existing policy which is not controlled by CloudFormation. Have I misunderstood the issue?

Comment: I was looking at this and thinking it can be done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47931342/how-to-change-s3-bucket-policies-with-cloudformation

Comment: @JeremyThompson I will double check it using my own bucket and policies. For now I can remove the answer, until then. Thanks for letting me know:_)

Comment: “ The only thing you can do is to replace policy in the bucket using CloudFormation by recreating it.” how can you do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a [CustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html), where you implement the logic for updating an existing bucket policy. Be sure to implement the handling of all resource events: Create, Update, Delete.

For example, here is an implementation for creating folders in S3:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-s3-custom-resources/